# Web Controls within UserControl null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, pageload

I've built a small User Control which is essentially a DropDownList with some preset Values based on what the Target-Property is set on.

Here's the Code:

```
public partial class Selector : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string SelectedValue { get {return this.ddl.SelectedValue; } }
    public int SelectedIndex { get { return this.ddl.SelectedIndex; } }
    public ListItem SelectedItem { get { return this.ddl.SelectedItem; } }
    private string target;
    public string Target { get { return this.target; } set { this.target = value; } }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddl.DataSource = target=="Group"?Util.GetAllGroups(Session["sessionId"].ToString()):Util.GetAllUsers(Session["sessionId"].ToString());
        ddl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

ASP-Markup:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Selector.ascx.cs" Inherits="InspireClient.CustomControls.Selector" %>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

If I insert my Selector into an aspx-Page it works just fine. 
Example:

```
<SCL:Selector Target="Group" runat="server" />
```

However, If I programmatically add it like this

```
ctrl = new Selector();
ctrl.Target = "User";
```

the DropDownList "ddl" is null and the application (logically) throws an error. Is Page_Load the wrong Method to do such a thing? What am I doing wrong?

I should add, "ctrl" is of type dynamic, not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Thanks in advance!

Dennis

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you're dynamically adding a user control and not a "simple" web control, you should use the [LoadControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) method to instantiate it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Selector yourControl = (Selector) LoadControl("Selector.ascx");
    yourControl.Target = "User";
    Controls.Add(yourControl);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! What exactly is the idea behind this instead of instantiating it the normal way?

Comment: @Dennis, user controls cannot really be instantiated "normally", because the markup defined in the `ascx` file has to be dynamically wrapped in a class that derives from the code-behind class (the exact same thing happens for `aspx` pages). Instantiating the code-behind class only gives you half of the control behavior.

Comment: This works! For me second line does not apply.  My web controls on the user control are no longer null!!!  Here's mine (to help with the pattern):     IndemnitorControl indemnitorControl =                                      (IndemnitorControl) LoadControl("IndemnitorControl.ascx");
    Controls.Add(indemnitorDataControl);